# how to generically handle Scala Higher-kinded types when coding factories for generating containers of items of type 'X'

Tags: scala, functional-programming

After working through some examples of Scala Higher-kinded types in [this tutorial](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html),  I started wondering if it is possible to write a method that generically handles two subclasses of a trait that 
is defined as a higher-kinded type.

The tutorial defines (a slightly more complex version of)  this trait:

```
trait ContainerFactory[M[_]] { def put[A](x: A): M[A] }
```

Which I understand as the  signature of a type parameterized factory that creates different kinds of containers (`Lists`, `Set`s, etc., where the type of container is given by `M`)  and where the type  of the object inserted into the container via the put method is given by `A`.  At the invocation site (I think that's the correct term) where you
instantiate the container, you specify the type of container you want (as in the line with the comment: `//factory for List containers)`

```
val factory = new ContainerFactory[List] { def put[A](x: A) = List(x)  } // factory for List containers
factory.put("dog") // insert an element of type String to factory
res5: List[String] = List(dog)          //  and you get a List of String

factory.put(1)// insert an element of type Int to factory
res6: List[Int] = List(1) // and you get a List of Int

val factory2 = new ContainerFactory[Set] { def put[A](x: A) = Set(x)} // factory for Set containers
factory2.put("dog")
factory2.put(1)
```

My goal is to create a method that takes a `ContainerFactory` 
and an object to put into the generated container. I would like that method to generate the appropriate container (`List` or `Set`) parameterized to hold the type of object that I pass in as the second object.

I think a method like the one below would be really cool and useful, but I am having trouble with the Scala syntax to get it to work.  In fact, I don't even know if it is possible.

```
// Code below does not compile
// Method for generating container (of type defined by first arg) that contains the second argument, and 
// which (after instantiation) is parameterized to hold  only objects of that type:

def genContainer[M[T]](factory: ContainerFactory[M], item : T) = {
    factory.put(item)
}


genContainer(factory2, "x")
// desired return value =>    Set[String] = Set(x)

genContainer(factory, 11)
// desired return value =>    List[Int] = List(11)
```

Note: the error I get when I try to define `genContainer` is:

```
<console>:10: error: not found: type T
       def genContainer[M[T]]( factory :  Container[M]  ,  item : T) = {
```

Note 2:   I can define  a method like this, which takes a generic `ContainerFactory`

```
def genContainer[M[T]](factory:  ContainerFactory[M]) = { }
```

But when I try to specify the second argument as type `T`  (which is referenced in the parameterization) I get the error about `T` not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close:

```
def genContainer[T, M[_]](factory:  ContainerFactory[M], item: T) = {
    factory.put(item)
}
```

All you have to do is specify each type parameter as a top-level type parameter!  And the compiler is smart enough to deduce these type parameters under many circumstances:

```
val factory = new ContainerFactory[List] { def put[A](x: A) = List(x)  }
genContainer(factory, "foo") //No need to specify the type parameters!
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close. The issue is that you need to declare your type parameters separately:

```
def genContainer[T, M[_]](factory: ContainerFactory[M], item: T) =
  factory.put(item)
```

This is a little confusing because the following compiles:

```
def genContainer[M[T]](factory: ContainerFactory[M]) = "whatever"
```

The scope of the `T` here is limited to the inside of the `M[...]`, though (see section 4.4 of [the language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf) for details). This can be convenient when you're declaring fancy bounds like `M[T <: Foo[T]]`, but in general giving the type parameter of the type constructor a name is just noise, and it's best to go with `M[_]` (which is exactly equivalent to `M[A]`).