# Scala implicit ambiguity doesn't get resolved without annoying dummy argument to mark the type.

Tags: scala, functional-programming

After working through some examples of Scala higher-kinded types in [this](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html) tutorial,  I started playing around with 
(a) implicits and  (b) techniques for writing methods that generically handle subclasses of a trait that 
is defined as a  higher-kinded type.  I already got a great answer on (b)  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835894/how-to-generically-handle-scala-higher-kinded-types-when-coding-factories-for-ge)  which is moving me closer to solving the problem below:

*I want to create a factory for creating singleton containers (Sets, Lists, Arrays) that wrap 
the item that I pass in to the factory function.*   [ Even if there is already a Scala 
library that does this, I'm doing this as a learning exercise. But, hey... if there is one, please let me know!]

The end result should let me do this:

```
scala> var j: Set[String] =  wrapItemInContainer("foo")
j: Set[String] = Set(foo)

scala> var k: List[Int] =  wrapItemInContainer(9)
k: List[Int] = List(9)
```

The solution I came up with is shown below.  I have to supply an annoying dummy final argument so that I can 
help the compiler figure out what kind of container I want.  This works, but I am puzzled by the fact that the 
type signature of the variable that I want to assign the result to  (j, k..etc.) is not giving the 
compiler enough information to figure out which implicitly defined ContainerFactory needs to be used.

This clunky solution works:

```
trait ContainerFactory[M[_]]  { def put[A](x: A): M[A]  }


implicit val factory = new ContainerFactory[List] { def put[A](x: A) = List(x)  }   // factory for List containers
implicit val factory2 = new ContainerFactory[Set] { def put[A](x: A) = Set(x)}    // factory for Set containers

def wrapItemInContainer[ M[A]: ContainerFactory, A](item: A,  helper: M[A]) : M[A] = { 
    val c = implicitly[ContainerFactory[M]]                             
    c.put(item)
}

var j: List[Int] =  wrapItemInContainer(9, List(0))
```

But I really want something with out the noisy second argument:

```
def wrapItemInContainer[ M[A]: ContainerFactory, A](item: A) : M[A] = { 
    val c = implicitly[ContainerFactory[M[A]]]                             
    c.put(item)
}

var j: List[Int] =  wrapItemInContainer(9)    // this does not work.
```

I get this error:

```
<console>:17: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both value factory of type => ContainerFactory[List]
 and value factory2 of type => ContainerFactory[Set]
 match expected type ContainerFactory[M]
       var j: List[Int] =  wrapItemInContainer(9)
```

Any ideas or tips are much appreciated !

-chris

Comment: To let you know: that's what sometimes is called "Pointed". It is usually part of the Applicative type class, e.g., in [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/466d4da2951666f736d554104a2b3b956e4e6885/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make the factory covariant in M. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-language/dQEomVCH3CI and https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7332.

This compiles:

```
import language.higherKinds

trait Factory[+M[_], A] { def put(x: A): M[A] }

implicit def factory1[A] =
  new Factory[List, A] { def put(x: A) = List(x) }
implicit def factory2[A] =
  new Factory[Set, A] { def put(x: A) = Set(x) }

def wrap[M[_], A](a: A)(
    implicit factory: Factory[M, A]): M[A] =
  factory.put(a)

val j: Set[String] = wrap("foo")
val k: List[Int] = wrap(9)
```

I've taken the liberty of shortening your names. I also followed the advice you received at [how to generically handle Scala Higher-kinded types when coding factories for generating containers of items of type 'X'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29835894/86485) to make A a type parameter on the factory itself.